# How to properly make a Mongoose post hook async

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a very simple post `findOneAndDelete` hook in my application. I'm using this hook to cascade delete all documents that contain the user's id when that user closes their account.

```
UserSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function({ _id }, next) {
  try {
    await Exercise.deleteMany({ user: _id });
    await Tag.deleteMany({ user: _id });
    await Template.deleteMany({ user: _id });
    await Workout.deleteMany({ user: _id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

The hook seems to work exactly as I want it, but by marking the hook as async, I'm running into the below error from my ESLint setup. It doesn't seem like post hooks are supposed to return Promises.

```
Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.
```

I read in the Mongoose documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post-async) that you can chain async post hooks by sequentially calling `next()` at the bottom of your functions. But this seems repetitive to have to do this multiple times when I can accomplish this in the body of a single function that's marked as async.

My question is: can I ignore my linter? Or am I misusing this hook, and should I refactor to what the Mongoose documentation suggests?

Mongoose version: `5.7.4`

Comment: `next()` needs to be called as it's required for calling next chains like Express middlewares.

Comment: @mcrunix I refactored to make 4 sequential `next()` calls. But I'm still not sure why I'm not supposed to to make post hooks async (according to my linter).