# Mongoose post hook does not returns response in Postman when saving with await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm creating a post hook to create a slug after the a Post has been save. When I try and use Postman the check my result, the process go into limbo (no data was returned).I am using `mongoose@8.0.0`.

Code for the post hook:

```
PostsSchema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
  try {
    doc.postSlug = slugify(doc.postTitle, { lower: true });
    await doc.save();
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("inside catch method");
    return next(createError(500, err.message));
  }
});
```

Code for the route I use:

```
module.exports.createPost = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { postTitle, postContent, postAuthor } = req.body;
  try {
    // check if author exist
    const authorExist = await AccountsModel.findById(postAuthor);
    if (!authorExist) {
      return next(createError(404, `Author ID: ${postAuthor} Not Found`));
    }
    // create post
    console.log("route 1")
    const postNew = new PostsModel({
      postTitle: postTitle,
      postContent: postContent,
      postAuthor: postAuthor,
    });
    await postNew.save();
    // populate data for return
    let postCreated = await postNew.populate("postAuthor");
    return res.status(200).json({
      code: 1,
      success: true,
      message: "New Post Created",
      data: postCreated,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(createError(500, error.message));
  }
};
```

I did fix this by removing the `await` in front of the `doc.save()`:

```
PostsSchema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
  try {
    doc.postSlug = slugify(doc.postTitle, { lower: true });
    doc.save();
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("inside catch method");
    return next(createError(500, err.message));
  }
});
```

Also, using `.then()` also return the result:

```
PostsSchema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
  doc.postSlug = slugify(doc.postTitle, { lower: true });
  console.log(1);
  doc
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(2);
      return next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return next(createError(500, err.message));
    });
});
```

But found some other post what have await and the answers indicate that it is not the problem:

- [How to properly make a Mongoose post hook async](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61164374/14723731)
- [Mongoose post save hook , update the document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65142450/14723731)
- [Async function in mongoose pre save hook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48799479/14723731). pre hook seems to work just fine with the await.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76738359/14723731. This one is the same as mine where they don't use an await method

So, I am wondering is it the await that break the process or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, when I `console.log(1)` within your post hook, it creates an infinite loop. Based on a comment under 1 of the post [Mongoose post save hook , update the document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65142450/14723731), post hook is executed after a `.save()` is performed; and inside your post hook, you perform another `.save()` which call your post hook again, creating an infinite loop.

Your `await doc.save()` doesn't work because it's waiting for the infinite loop to complete. That is why there is no response in postman, it never reached the `return next()` section.

Your `doc.save()` "works" because `.save()` is asynchronous; before it could complete its process, it has already reached to the `return next()` section that is why there is a value returned to postman while the code stays in an infinite loop.

Your `doc.save().then()` "works" because `.then()` resolves your `.save()` and get to the `return next()` but it invokes the post hook again, creating an infinite loop.

I recommend either change the keyword pass in the hook or change to pre hook:

```
PostsSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('PostTitle')) {
        this.slug = slugify(this.PostTitle, { lower: true });
    }
    return next();
});
```

This pre hook runs before the actual `save()` operation, so you don't call this hook again after saving it.